# Google analytics within lightbox issue

Tags: asp.net, analytics

I am attempting to send a custom variable to google analytics with a returned value in a lightbox.  As far as I can tell the value is returning appropriately, and even if it weren't I have tested with simple strings for the custom variable.  Strangely the custom variable appears to be pushed to the queue but when I then push a track event, the track event fires, seemingly without sending the custom variable along.

I have been looking for days for someone who has had a seemingly similar issue and can not find any good resource. Could anyone please help?  This is the latest version of relevant code.  There are no other analytics calls in the lightbox.  domain name and account changed to x's:

```
            <asp:HiddenField ID="ProfessionValue" runat="server" />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var chosenProfCode = document.form1.ProfessionValue.value + '';
                var _gaq = _gaq || [];

                _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XX-XXXXXXX']);
                _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.xxxxxxxx']);
                _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Visitor Type', chosenProfCode, 1]);
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

                (function () {
                    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                })();

            </script>
```

---

I have also tried wrapping the custom var in a function with a subsequent "trackEvent" call, etc.

Please help!

---

Also posted to the google analytics community: 
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=67a119f52ada0b07&hl=en